# The page accessed using the symbolic / soft link doesn't change its content as it was cached (cache cleared)

Tags: symlink

Whenever I try to access the path https://example.com/example/symlink, the page remains the same as it was before.

The symbolic link points to the Laravel Public directory https://example.com/example/laravel/laravel/public but that's not a question about the Laravel framework.

I changed the background color in the .css file and when I try to access a website using the https://example.com/example/symlink the CSS rules don't apply while using the https://example.com/example/laravel/laravel/public works perfectly.

It couldn't be an issue with the Laravel framework, it has to do with the symbolic links.

Comment: "it has to do with the symbolic links" - or browser cache. Or proxy cache. Or a number of other things. Including, indeed, some code in laravel. Symbolic links "just work". I'd look elsewhere.

Comment: And if I open the same page in a different browser, it works :/

Comment: I'm using cloudflare cache, I guess it could be the thing - proxy cache.

Comment: Yap, that's the problem with the cloudflare cache. Thanks :)